# Invoking function which accept functions as parameters

Tags: scala

Below worksheet code defines two functions.
fun accepts a function parameter of type `Int => Int` and invokes the function
with parameter value 2

`funParam` accepts an Int parameter and returns this parameter + 3.

This is a contrived example so as gain an intuition of how functions are passed
around when writing functional code.

```
object question {
  println("Welcome to the Scala worksheet")       //> Welcome to the Scala worksheet

    def fun(f : Int => Int) = {
        f(2)
    }                                         //> fun: (f: Int => Int)Int

    def funParam(param : Int) : Int = {
        param + 3
    }                                         //> funParam: (param: Int)Int

    fun(funParam)                             //> res0: Int = 5

}
```

Why can't I use something like : fun(funParam(3))
This causes compiler error : `type mismatch; found : Int required: Int => Int`

Does this mean I cannot invoke function "fun" passing a variable into funParam ?
This is what I attempt to achieve using fun(funParam(3)) , perhaps there is an way of achieving this ?

Comment: @Marth I was expecting "funParam(3)" to be passed as function to "fun" but it seems I don't fully understand how functions are evaluated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you can use:

```
val res = fun(_ => funParam(3))
println(res) // 6
```

You can't pass a value of type `Int` (the result of calling `funParam(3)`) to `fun` which parameter is of type `Int => Int` (`Function1[-T1, +R]`).

Comment: thanks, can you explain the use of the wildcard notation in this context ?

Comment: It means that lambda argument is not used or has no sense. In this case 2 from your f(2) call.

Answer (score 0):

> Why can't I use something like : fun(funParam(3)) This causes compiler
>   `error : type mismatch; found : Int required: Int => Int`

because `funParam(3)` evaluates to a *value* of type `Int` but `fun` takes a function of type `Int => Int`