# Function evaluation

Tags: function, scala, functional-programming

In this question [Invoking function which accept functions as parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27677793/invoking-function-which-accept-functions-as-parameters) is this also a valid explanation of why the code does not compile?

funParam(3) is a valid invocation but fun(funParam(3)) is not. funParam(3) is not evaluated until compilation so the compiler cannot accept this as a valid parameter.

I think I'm confused as it's common practice to pass parameters to functions pre compilation but it is not valid to pass functions which contain parameters to functions pre compilation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may be confusing a couple concepts.

It's worth thinking about *why* a function might take another function as a parameter. Given `fun: (Int => Int) => Int` (a function that takes a function of `Int => Int` as a parameter and returns an `Int`), presumably, `fun` is planning to pass an `Int` to its argument, and return some modified version of the result. This pattern is used frequently in functional programming, like when we pass functions to `map` or `reduce` that operate on values inside a collection. The argument of type `Int => Int` to `fun` is essentially a calculation with a "hole" in it, and it's counting on `fun` or some other operation to provide the `Int` it needs to be fully evaluated.

`funParam(3)` doesn't have any unspecified variables, and it will be evaluated immediately whenever it's referred to. That's why the type of `funParam(3)` is `Int`. Sure, `funParam` itself is `Int => Int`, but since you've given it the `Int` parameter `3`, the type of the whole expression is just the return type: `Int`.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is because `fun` expects `Int => Int` as an argument, but `funParam(3)` is not of that type. Its type is `Int`.

Answer (score 1):

Given

```
def funParam(i: Int): Int = ...
```

You can treat the method`funParam` as a function with type `Int => Int`

But `funParam(3)` is *not a function*, it is a concrete value--an `Int`, and therefore not `Int => Int`

So you cannot pass an `Int` to a method that is expecting `Int => Int`.